# codeception with selenium webDriver gives an error for systemProperty

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeception

I am trying to run a test with `codeception` in `selenium webDriver`. For starting the driver I use this command

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver='path to chrome driver' selenium-server-standalone-3.2.0.jar
```

However when I start to run the test I get the error message: `the path to driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property...`

But as I understand I am have already given the path to driver, so how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've strugled a few hours as with this one before.  Your command is true if you are using selenium version 2.

I've moved to version 3.  This is not very wel documented, but the Dwebdriver option must now be passed before -jar parameter.

That will give you something lime this:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/your-dir/chromedriver -jar /your-dir/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -port 4444'
```

or for multiple drivers:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/your-dir/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/your-dir/geckodriver -jar /your-dir/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -port 4444'
```